# Disable warning messages in Sourcegrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, grid

Is it possible to disable warning message boxes in [sourcegrid](https://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/), like this one:

```
"Given cell at position ... intersects with another cell at position ..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do that.
What I did was check the conditions that gave the warning before adding cells